# Stop a bash command as soon as a (specific) error is written to stderr

Tags: bash

I have a simple rsync task running as follows:

```
while :
do
rsync -rLvz --size-only --ipv4 --progress source target
done
```

The reason for this is that after a point, the rsync command fails with the following error:

```
rsync: send_files failed to open "/source/filename": Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
```

And then errors for all remaining untransferred files in the rsync file list, and restarts the rsync.

I realize that the while loop I have here is as simple as they come. Is it possible to stop and restart the rsync as soon as the first error appears?

I have googled the heck out of this and will keep looking, but any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: ...the question doesn't really have anything to do with the loop -- you'd have the same problem if you wanted to stop `rsync` the moment it emitted that error even if you *didn't* want to have it in a loop that would restart it. I'm taking the liberty of editing appropriately.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, that makes sense and is helpful.